# Xamarin BaseDirectory

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I build an mobile app with xamarin.forms, and i'm facing a problem.
I would to use a JSON file as dictionnary.

The class "StaticData" that manages the JSON files is in "Utilities" folder, and the JSON files is in "Resources" folder.

In the StaticData class, i would to retrieve the current folder to be able to read the JSON file.

```
string path = string.Format(@"{0}{1}{2}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Ressources\", fileName);
```

But, BaseDirectory is Null.
Could you help me read my JSON file please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I did this :
'#if __IOS__
            var resourcePrefix = "namespace.iOS.Resources.";
            #endif
            #if __ANDROID__
            var resourcePrefix = "namespace.Droid.Resources.";
            #endif'